# Quiz database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

Hi i'm working on a quiz system and i'm stuck on the last table `user_quiz` on how to link it to other tables? I want it to keep track of the score the user got on the quiz and also the total number of quizzes that the user has taken.

The userid is the primary key, but im stuck on what the foreign key should be, so that I could link the tables together. I have also been trying to normalize my database, so if anyone could help me with what the foreign key should be, and if the database isn't normalised, could help me normalise it. Thank you:)

Users

```
    +-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
    |userid     | email       |username   |password     |
    +-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
    |  1        |             |           |             |
    |  2        |             |           |             |
    +-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+


    Module
    +-----------+-------------+
    | module_id | module_name |
    +-----------+-------------+
    |  1        | Forces      |
    |  2        | Magnetism   |
    |  3        | Electricity |
    |  4        | Gravitation |
    +-----------+-------------+

    Questions
    +------------+-----------+-----------------+
    | question_id| module_id | question        |
    +------------+-----------+-----------------+
    |  1         | 1         | Define a Newton |
    |  2         | 1         | Define Work Done|
    |  3         | 2         | Define Magnetism|
    |  4         | 2         | Define a Tesla  |
    |  5         | 3         | Define Current  |
    +------------+-----------+-----------------+
    Choices
    +----------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
    | choice_id| question_id | choices           |is_correct|
    +----------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
    |  1       | 1           | Answer 1          |  0       |
    |  2       | 1           | Answer 2          |  0       |
    |  3       | 1           | Answer 3          |  0       |
    |  4       | 1           | Answer 4          |  1       |
    |  5       | 2           | Answer 1          |  0       |
    |  6       | 2           | Answer 2          |  0       |
    |  7       | 2           | Answer 3          |  0       |
    |  8       | 2           | Answer 4          |  1       |
    |  9       | 3           | Answer 1          |  0       |
    |  10      | 3           | Answer 2          |  0       |
    |  11      | 3           | Answer 3          |  0       |
    |  12      | 3           | Answer 4          |  1       |
    +----------+-------------+-------------------+----------+

    user_quiz
    +-----------+-------------+---------------------+------------+
    |userid     |  score      | total_quizzes_taken |     ?      |
    +-----------+-------------+---------------------|------------+
    |  1        |             |                     |            |
    |  2        |             |                     |            |
    +-----------+-------------+---------------------+------------+
```

Comment: In my opinion, user_quiz should add one field user_quiz_id as a primary key and userid should be foreign key. Once you add a row, just use sql procedure to search userid, if column userid contain inserted_userid, do your own business, else, normally add new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A `FOREIGN KEY` is not required for linking two tables.
- The total number of quizzes is computable, don't store it.
- `UserQuiz` is a many:many mapping table?  Then it has `user_id`, `quiz_id` and `score`.  See [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for optimal schema a many:many table.

Number of quizzes taken by user_id = 123:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM UserQuiz
    WHERE user_id = 123;
```

But there is a potential problem.  I assume entries are added as Questions are answered and graded?  That `COUNT` will probably give you the number of quizzes *started*, not *completed*.  If that is not satisfactory, you need to explain how you know that a quiz is *completed*.

Comment: Thank you for telling me that the total amount of quizzes can be removed.

Comment: A quiz is completed once a quiz_id value is stored in the database. However I have been looking at the link you have given me, and I'm a bit confused. Should I get rid of the quiz_id as there is no need for a primary key, and if so what should my composite key be made of?

Comment: @Zestyy99 - The composite PK is the pair of ids.